# TestNg using Ant

Tags: ant, testng

When I run Test NG test using testng.xml, it runs fine but if i run testng.xml using ant (Build.xml), it gives an error Cannot fine class in classpath

Testng.xml:-

?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Build.xml:-

```
<xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml"/>
```

Comment: Which class is not - testng or test class?  Can you post a bit more of the build.xml snippet?

Comment: I had put he entire file i dont know why its not displayed any ways putting it again

Comment: <target name="testng">
<property name="test.base.output.dir" location="testng_output"/>
<mkdir dir="${test.base.output.dir}"/>
<tstamp><format property="DAY_TIME_NOW" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss" /></tstamp>
<property name="test.output.dir" location="${test.base.output.dir}/testng_output_${DAY_TIME_NOW}"/>
<mkdir dir="${test.output.dir}"/>
<taskdef  name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" >
<classpath>
<pathelement location="../lib/testng-5.12.1.jar"/>
</classpath></taskdef>
<testng  outputdir="${test.output.dir}" >
<xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml"/> 
</testng> </target>

Comment: xml code seems to be OK. Please check your configuration

Answer (score 1):

```
<xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml">
```

Certainly the error is in this line.Its looking for compiled classes in the base directory(dir=".").point dir to bin folder where the compiled classes would be usually or wherever you have kept the compile classes.here an example:

```
<xmlfileset dir="${basedir}/bin" includes="testng.xml">
```